# Bash script hangs until Enter is pressed. Only shows new mac address, no message box

Tags: bash, pid

I am learning bash, and I wanted to automate a series of commands that I use often. In this case it is macchanger, and restarting network-manager.

```
#!/bin/bash

#Automated macchanger script

wlanDOWN=$(ifconfig wlan0 down)

change_mac=$(macchanger -r wlan0)

wlanUP=$(ifconfig wlan0 up)

verify=$(macchanger --show wlan0)

network_connect=$(sudo service network-manager restart)

confirmation=$(dialog --msgbox "Change complete" 10 30)

printf "%s\n" "$wlanDOWN"
printf "%s\n" "$change_mac"
printf "%s\n" "$wlanUP"
printf "%s\n" "$verify"

printf "%s\n" "To return to permanent mac address type 'macchanger --permanent <interface name>' "

printf "%s\n" "$network_connect"

printf "%s\n" "$confirmation"
```

When I execute this script with

```
./hide_me
```

it just hangs until I press Enter a second time, then it just shows the new mac address and doesn't show my message box. Any pointers? Thanks friends.

Comment: `while [ kill -0 "$pid" ]` is wrong, you probably meant `while kill -0 "$pid"`. You should post a complete example if you want more help.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I thought I pasted the code before I submitted. It's there now. :D

Comment: I removed the brackets, and now I get: line 32: kill: `': not a pid or valid job spec

Comment: Probably because your `pid` variable is an empty string. Try printing it out before the while loop maybe.

Comment: You probably want to get this working in the simplest possible way and then worry about bells and whistles like spinners.

Comment: @pvg Hey, I'm completely cool with that. I can add the fun stuff later. :)

Comment: @arzyfex It's the code you see above in my question. :)

Comment: @pvg I removed anything related to the progress spinner, and it restarts my network-manager, but it's still hanging until I press Enter again, then it just shows the new mac address and no message box. O.o

Comment: @IRGeekSauce edit your question with your new and simplified code so people can see what it's doing.

Comment: @IRGeekSauce ok, what happens when you get rid of the whole dialog bit?

Comment: @pvg If I remove the message box at the end, it displays the new mac address as intended, and restarts my network-manager, also as intended. Would you know why the message dialog wouldn't show before? At least this is progress.

Comment: I don't really know much about `dialog` or how to use it properly, I imagine it has a voluminous man page, though. You should probably write up a [MCVE] that shows the specific problem you're having with it. Alternatively, you can just keep it oldskool and get your bash sea legs writing straightforward console scripts rather than text GUIs, the way god intended such things to be :)

Comment: @pvg Hey, I got no problem with that. :-) The dialog box is similar to the setup process of things such as mySQL. It's just a dialog within terminal. type "dialog --msgbox "Hello World" 10 30 " and you'll see. So, how can this question be "answered" now? I can +1 your comment at least.

Comment: Right but the setup process for things like MySQL and the like on debian/ubuntu are kind of the exception (and quite specific to those distros), your typical shell portable script usually just does its thing (while potentially echoing status) and moves on. So, generally, start with that. If you want to add these distro-specific GUI-like features, that's fine too but then try to isolate the specific problems related to them and write questions about them. You can answer your own question, incidentally, if you've figured out something satisfactory.

Answer (score 0):

Removed the dialog box, and it does what it's supposed to do.

```
#!/bin/bash

#Automated macchanger script

wlanDOWN=$(ifconfig wlan0 down)

change_mac=$(macchanger -r wlan0)

wlanUP=$(ifconfig wlan0 up)

verify=$(macchanger --show wlan0)

network_connect=$(sudo service network-manager restart)

confirmation=$(dialog --msgbox "Change complete" 10 30)

printf "%s\n" "$wlanDOWN"
printf "%s\n" "$change_mac"
printf "%s\n" "$wlanUP"
printf "%s\n" "$verify"

printf "%s\n" "To return to permanent mac address type 'macchanger --permanent <interface name>' "

printf "%s\n" "$network_connect"
```

I learned something today: K.I.S.S. ;-)